# VBA Worksheet_Calculate Not Triggering

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro in **Excel 2007** to link the **x**-axis of a chart to a specified cells in the worksheet. The cells that I'm targeting for my max and min axis values contain the `INDEX` function which I'm using in conjunction with a scroll bar. As the scroll bar moves, the cell values change according to the `INDEX` function, and I'm trying to link these changes to the **x**-axis on the chart.

I can't get the following code to execute:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart
      Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$H$47"
          .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Target.Value
        Case "$H$34"
         .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Target.Value
      End Select
  End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Kara

Comment: Is the subroutine recorded in the `ThisWorkbook` object instead of a VBA Module?

Comment: Worksheet_Calculate() does not have a `Target` object.  Since it is just two remove the Select case and just use the Range.Value: `.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Range("$H$47").Value`

Comment: The subroutine is recorded in 'Sheet1'. @Jordan

Comment: @ScottCraner After removing Select case, it now says "Method MaximumScale of object Axis failed".

Comment: I figured it out. @ScottCraner you're suggestion worked after I changed the xlCategory to xlValue. I thought xlCategory was always the x-axis but apparently for a bar graph xlValue is the x-axis. Thank you all !!